# Distance between two std::List

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have two `std::list`, which each one has a positional vector `m_Pos`. I'm newbie to `std::list`, and I would to calculate the distance between each index in those two lists and store them in an array. This is what I have done, I dont know if it is the correct way or not

The problem is the dir vector which has the distances are not in ordered manner, I want for example to store the distane between positions Acurrent and Aprev, Bcurrent, Bprev, to be stored in order in the dir vector so that I can correlate later between them, so that I say  dir[0] is the distance between Acurr, Aprev..etc

```
if(objs.size() == m_prev_objs.size())
{
    std::vector<Vec2f> dir;
    std::list< Obj >::iterator prevIter = m_prev_objs.begin();
    std::list< Obj >::iterator currIter = objs.begin();

    //  Vec2f dis = currIter->m_Pos - prevIter->m_Pos;  
    for (std::list< Obj >::iterator currIter = objs.begin(); currIter != objs.end(); ++currIter ) 
    {

        dir.push_back(currIter->m_Pos - prevIter->m_Pos);

    }

           prevIter++;

}
```

Comment: It looks okay, except for that funky loop in the middle that sometimes prints out `"fdfdfd"`. What do you want the code to do, and what does it do that's different from what you want?

Comment: It looks like the code should do what you describe (although the check for `prevIter != end()` is redundant, since you've already checked that both lists are the same size). Does it compile, run, and give the expected results? If it does, what is the question? If it doesn't, what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: The problem is the dir vector which has the distances are not in ordered manner, I want for example to store the distane between positions Acurrent and Aprev, Bcurrent, Bprev, to be stored in order in the dir vector so that I can correlate later between them, so that I say dir[0] is the distance between Acurr, Aprev..etc

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (whatever question that is), but you *could* compress the code further by putting both iterators into the for loop, aswell as their checking end conditions and incrementing them.

Comment: @MoazELdeen: What do you mean by "in order"? Your code puts them in the same order as they appear in the lists, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I agree. The order of dir appears to be preserved correctly.

Comment: I think it doesnt, so I tried to test that scenario. If I have two points A,B, the dir vector always have (0,0), (x,y), if A is not moving and B is moving, also if A is moving and B isnot moving, the result is the same (0,0), (x,y) <-- some values

Comment: @MoazELdeen: That shouldn't happen given the code you've posted. Perhaps you could post a complete, compilable test case to show what the problem is?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I have two points A, B. When I try to move A, and leave B, the dir vector always have (0,0), (distance), even If I try to move B and leave, dir vector always have (0,0), (distance), and sometimes dir gets 3 elements however I only have two points!!

Comment: @MoazELdeen: You've changed the code now so that `prevIter++` is outside the loop; that's certainly wrong. If you put it back where it was, at the end of the loop (or even as part of the loop's iteration expression), then it should work as you want it to. If your real code doesn't work, then please post that; we can't guess what's wrong with it unless we can see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using standard algorithms, note the action can be lambda if you have access to C++11

```
 inline Vec2f action(const Objs& o1, const Objs& o2) {
       return o1->m_Pos
            - o2->m_Pos;
 }


 //elsewhere
 std::vector<Vec2f> dir;
 dir.reserve(objs.size());

 std::transform(
      objs.begin(),        
      objs.end(), 
      m_prev_objs.begin(), 
      std::back_inserter(dir),
      action
 );
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter

Comment: it crashes and gives list iterator not referencable

Comment: then you are doing something wrong. post your new code. Also assert that the lists are the same length.

Comment: it is working now thanks, would you show me the solution without using transform and back_insereter please ? I'm interested.

Comment: @Moaz ELdeen: sorry I genuinely consider transform to be the correct solution, using manual loops with containers feels like dirty hacks to me.

Comment: what If I want to modifiy const objs in action inline.. so that I do some calculations rather than the difference ?

Comment: @Moaz ELdeen: remove the const keyword, it's modify the version in the lists, if that's not the behaviour your want remove the `&` so you pass in by value. The const just allows us to reason about the algorithm better, that the two input lists' elements won't be modified.

Comment: 'cinder::Vec2f (Obj &,Obj &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const Obj' to 'Obj &'
this is when I passed just referenced object..

Comment: are either of the lists const, really can't answer these question without seeing the code.